# Mysql sum fields based on value of other field

Tags: mysql

Given the following table

```
sku     store     sold
SKU_1   store_1   22
SKU_2   store_1   10
SKU_3   store_1   15
SKU_1   store_2   10
SKU_2   store_2   50
SKU_3   store_2   10
SKU_1   store_3   1
SKU_2   store_3   4
SKU_3   store_3   61
```

What would be the query to find out:

1. How many SKU_1 were sold in store_1 and store_2
2. How many SKU_2 were sold in any store greater than store_1 i.e. it could be store_2 and store_3 in this example but potentially more with more stores in

Answer (score 0):

How many `SKU_1` were sold in `store_1` and `store_2`

```
select sum(sold) as SKU_1_sold
from tbl
where  sku = 'SKU_1'
and store in ('store_1', 'store_2')
```

How many `SKU_2` were sold in any store greater than `store_1`

```
select sum(sold) as SKU_2_sold
from tbl
where  sku = 'SKU_2'
and store > 'store_1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation for this when doing aggregation on different conditions something as

```
select
sum( 
  case 
    when sku = 'SKU_1' and store in('store_1','store_2') then sold 
    else 0 
  end
 ) as sold1,
sum( 
  case 
    when sku = 'SKU_2' and store <> 'store_1' then sold 
    else 0 
  end
) as sold2
from table_name
```